# Highcharts Arearange has no zoom animation above certain length

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, zooming

I am building a Highcharts visualisation where there is a line series, and an area series that hugs it (as the error of that series).

My problem is that when I add the arearange, the zoom animation no longer works. The zoom animation works just fine without the arearange series and, strangely enough, the zoom animation works fine if there are eight data points in the area range, but not if there are nine or above.

I have created a codepen to demonstrate this: http://codepen.io/samirelanduk/pen/eWgdZN

The two highcharts files I am pulling in are:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Does anybody know why this is? Is it a bug (known or unknown) within Highcharts, or have I done something wrong? Or is there a very good reason for why it does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of the points is higher than 99, then the animation for zooming is disabled, unless you force it by setting `chart.animation` to `true`. I cannot find whether it is documented, sadly, but it can be seen in the function responsible for zooming.

In `chart.prototype.zoom`:

```
// Redraw
  if (hasZoomed) {
    chart.redraw(
       pick(chart.options.chart.animation, event && event.animation, chart.pointCount < 100) // animation
    );
  }
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWgBMw